# MS GRAPH API Upload v1.0 endpoint corrupts DOCX

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api

Was trying to upload docx files through a golang server using MS graph API, and although I was able to upload pdfs, when I tried uploading docx files the files were being corrupted when sent over. If I upload the same file through the OneDrive website, there would be no problems.

To isolate the issue I tried making the API calls through postman using a link like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/pqv2-dev-svc@novacoast.com/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}:/filename.docx:/content
```

used a bearer token.

the additional header of `Content-Type` of which I have tried the values:

```
text/plain
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

and uploaded the file with the `form-data` option under the body tab but with no luck, the file always gets corrupted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved] Was sending file as form-data instead of binary!